# Optimise SQL query joined on DATE(datetime) = date?

Tags: sql, mysql, optimization, query-optimization

I have two tables: one has a datetime column, the other has a date column.

I want to join the two tables like this:

```
SELECT
  t1.dt,
  t2.d
FROM
  table1 t1,
JOIN
  table2 t2
ON
  DATE(t1.dt) = t2.date
```

But obviously, this kills the index on `t1.dt`.

What's the best strategy to get around this? The simplest approach would be to add a new column to `t1` (and set it equal to `date(t1.dt)`), but I don't like the idea of duplicating data.

Is there a neat way to get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your datetime column consists of a date and a time part. As you would like to index the date part individually, it would make sense to split the datetime column into two individual column, one for the time part and the other one for the date part. The date column can then be indexed and the index can be used in your query. With this approach you do not duplicate any data at all.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure, but this might force MySQL to iterate all rows as you substract a date from the datetime. You should use EXPLAIN to be sure. You can get around this by doing something like this:

```
(t1.dt >= "2010-06-24 00:00:00"
  AND t1.dt < ("2010-06-24 00:00:00" + INTERVAL 1 DAY) )
```

Edit: Just tried using Date(), and it seems MySQL still uses indexes:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t1 (
    dt DATETIME,
    INDEX iDt (dt)
);

INSERT INTO t1 VALUES
    (NOW()),
    (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY),
    (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY),
    (NOW() - INTERVAL 2 DAY);

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t2 (
    dt DATETIME,
    INDEX iDt (dt)
);

INSERT INTO t2 VALUES
    (NOW()),
    (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY),
    (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY),
    (NOW() - INTERVAL 2 DAY);

# t1: Using index. t2: Using where+index
EXPLAIN EXTENDED
SELECT
    *
FROM t1
    JOIN t2 ON DATE(t1.dt) = DATE(t2.dt)
```

Comment: I tried something similar: `ON t1.td BETWEEN t2.date AND t2.date + INTERVAL 1 DAY`, and it makes it a bit faster, but the second half of the BETWEEN isn't indexed, so it's still using filesort and temporary.

Comment: Can you give do an explain extended and see what it says?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. This will make use of index

```
SELECT 
  t1.dt, 
  t2.d 
FROM 
  table1 t1, 
JOIN 
  table2 t2 
ON 
  t1.dt>=t2.date  and
  t1.dt <(t2.date + INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Comment: It does not seem to do so. It made may query hang.